# How do I print the 0s and 1s automatically in the 2D array and count the 1s and 0s in it?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, 2d

So far, my code is this one:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PG1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the length of matrix: ");

    //array indicates
    int i = input.nextInt();
    int j = i;

    //declaration,creation, initialization
    double [][] matrix =  new double [i][j];

    //print element in row i
    for (i = 0; i < matrix.length;i++){
      //print element j in row i
      for (j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print("The matrix is: " + matrix[i][j]);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

So basically, I want to print the 0s and 1s according to the user's input or row and column of the matrix. Your help will be much appreciated.

output:

Enter the length of the matrix: 4
The matrix:
0 1 1 1
 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 
1 1 1 1
All 0s on row 1 
All 1s on row 3
 No same numbers on a column 
No same numbers on the diagona

Comment: What do you mean the 0s and 1s? where are these coming from? are you wanting to have a user input a 1 or 0 and then place that into the matrix at the current position?

Comment: You are aware that SO is not a programmers-for-hire service for your homework, yes?

Comment: this is not a homework. just basically a practical classwork. it is something like this.   Enter the length of the matrix: 4
The matrix:
0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
1 1 1 1
All 0s on row 1
All 1s on row 3
No same numbers on a column
No same numbers on the diagonal

Answer (score 0):

you can achive like this:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.print("Enter the length of matrix: ");

//array indicates
int i = input.nextInt();
int j = i;
int count0s = 0;
int count1s = 0;

//declaration,creation,initialisation
 double [][] matrix =  new double [i][j];

//print element in row i
 for ( i = 0; i < matrix.length;i++){
    //print element j in row i
     for ( j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
         if(matrix[i][j] == 0){
              count0s++
              System.out.print("The matrix is: " + matrix[i][j]);
          }
         else if(matrix[i][j] == 1){
              count1s++
              System.out.print("The matrix is: " + matrix[i][j]);
          }

     }
     System.out.println("Total no. of 0s="+count0s);
     System.out.println("Total no. of 1s="+count1s);
 }




}
```

}

Comment: Enter the length of matrix: 4
The matrix is: 0.0The matrix is: 0.0The matrix is: 0.0The matrix is: 0.0Total no. of 0s=4
Total no. of 1s=0
The matrix is: 0.0The matrix is: 0.0The matrix is: 0.0The matrix is: 0.0Total no. of 0s=8
Total no. of 1s=0
The matrix is: 0.0The matrix is: 0.0The matrix is: 0.0The matrix is: 0.0Total no. of 0s=12
Total no. of 1s=0
The matrix is: 0.0The matrix is: 0.0The matrix is: 0.0The matrix is: 0.0Total no. of 0s=16
Total no. of 1s=0                                           it gave me this. how do i fix the error?

Comment: ohh .. put these lines outside both for loops

Comment: System.out.println("Total no. of 0s="+count0s);
     System.out.println("Total no. of 1s="+count1s);

Comment: ah it worked. no i just need to print the 0s and 1s. thank you for your help! i appreciates it.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to print 0s and 1s :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the length of matrix: ");

    //array indicates
    int i = input.nextInt();
    int j = i;
    int count0s = 0;
    int count1s = 0;

    //declaration,creation,initialisation
     double [][] matrix =  new double [i][j];

    //print element in row i
     for ( i = 0; i < matrix.length;i++){
        //print element j in row i
         for ( j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
             if(matrix[i][j] == 0)
                  count0s++
             else if(matrix[i][j] == 1)
                  count1s++
         }
     }
       System.out.println("Total no. of 0s="+count0s);
       System.out.println("Total no. of 1s="+count1s);
    }
    }
```

Comment: how do i this kind of output? Enter the length of the matrix: 4
The matrix:
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
All 0s on row 1 All 1s on row 3 No same numbers on a column No same numbers on the diagona